# how to get a linearized curve in some intervals

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions

in below picture I draw a graph base on weight of a controller system against cost function. I want to linearise and divide this curve to for example 5 five intervals. is there any function in mathematica to give me such a thing. I thinking first maybe I can get gradient of function and choose the nearest amount together.

[image]

Comment: You can, for example, select 6 points - they will define 5 intervals - and then compute the equations of the lines passing through two points at the time. Or you can get an interpolating function of order 1 to pass through those points. Look up `Interpolation`

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach. Given a function `f` to be plotted, I create a `Piecewise` function where I approximate the function with a linear equation for each interval starting at an odd integer. It's quite easy to adapt this solution for any interval setup.

```
f[x_] := 1/(x);

sol[min_, max_] := First@Solve[{f@min == a min + b, f@max == a max + b}, {a, b}];

linf[t_, {min_, max_, d_}] := Piecewise@Table[
    {If[OddQ@i, (a*t + b) /. sol[i, i + d], f@t], i <= t < i + d},
    {i, min, max - d, d}];

linf[x, {0, 5, 1}]
Plot[linf[x, {0, 5, 1}], {x, 0, 5}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[0, 5, 1], None},
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[.3, .3], Dashed],
 Mesh -> 4, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, MeshShading -> {Dashing[0], Dashed}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same with `Interpolation`. A `Quiet` is needed to prevent the appearance of some error messages related to the fact that `Plot` tries to sample the `InterpolatingFunction`-s outside their defined intervals as part of its adaptive sampling method.

```
linIntf[t_, {min_, max_, d_}] := Piecewise@Table[{If[OddQ@i, 
      Quiet@Interpolation[{{i, f[i]}, {i + d, f[i + d]}},
                          InterpolationOrder -> 1][t],
      f@t
      ], i <= t < i + d}, {i, min, max-d, d}];

linIntf[x, {0, 5, 1}]
Plot[linIntf[x, {0, 5, 1}], {x, 0, 5}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[0, 5, 1], None}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[.3, .3], Dashed], Mesh -> 4, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, MeshShading -> {Dashing[0], Dashed}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

My idea of using Interpolation is this.
You have a function defined in an interval [a,b]

```
f[x_] := 1/(1 + x)
a = 0; b = 6;
Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}, Frame -> True]
```

Define your n intervals

```
n = 5;
xrange = Range[a, b, (b - a)/n];
yrange = f[xrange];
```

And use Interpolation to create your piecewise linear approximation

```
linf = Interpolation[Transpose[{xrange, yrange}], InterpolationOrder -> 1]

Plot[linf[x], {x, 0, 6}]
```

You can fit all the steps in a single function that will return an interpolating function

> ```
> piecewiseLinearize[f_, {x_, a_, b_}, n_] := Module[{xrange, yrange},
>     xrange = Range[a, b, (b - a)/n];
>     yrange = (f /. x -> #) & /@ xrange;
>     Interpolation[Transpose[{xrange, yrange}], InterpolationOrder -> 1]
>     ]
> ```

Here's how to call it

```
linf = piecewiseLinearize[f[x], {x, 0, 6}, 5]

Plot[linf[x], {x, 0, 6}]
```